# mean time signals grouped by label

Tags: matlab, grouping, vectorization, mean

given a number of signals in a matrix, say `m [T x N]`
and a grouping variable `g [ 1 x N ]` with a number of labels `L < N`

is there an efficient, in-place way to compute mean time signals for every label?

A for loop

```
ml = zeros (T,L)

for i = 1:T
    for j = 1:L
        ml(i,j) = mean ( m(i,find(g==j)) )
    end
end
```

is a straightforward way to do it, but could there be a faster/cleaner way, possibly using vectorised code? Just to *(a)* get rid of for-loops and *(b)* assign `m = labelled_means(m, ...)` in one go. I read about `statarray`, but that looks much less efficient even than this for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could get rid of your outer loop really easily:

```
for j = 1:L
    ml(:,j) = mean(m(:,find(g==j)), 2)
end
```

Comment: fair enough -- I guess I put that in for dramatic effect :)

Comment: after some testing i found that the for-loop is both faster and more robust! arrayfun sometimes crashes when dimensions are not exact multiples of each other. the accumarray idead is nice, but it needs so many extra variables that the code is still cluttered, and slow. good old for-loop it is!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `arrayfun`. It will be cleaner, don't know if faster:

```
result = arrayfun(@(n) mean(A(:,find(g==n)),2),1:2,'UniformOutput',false);
result = reshape([result{:}],[],L)
```

For example, with data

```
A = [1 2 3 4;
     5 6 7 8;
     9 10 11 12];
L = 2;
g = [1 1 2 2];
```

this gives

```
result =

    1.5000    3.5000
    5.5000    7.5000
    9.5000   11.5000
```

Comment: excellent! arrayfun looks like 'advanced matlab' but this is what I was looking for!

Comment: @alle_meije just be warned though, `arrayfun` is very often slower than a loop

Answer (score 1):

You can use `accumarray`

```
[X,Y] = ndgrid(1:size(A,1), g);
accumarray([X(:) Y(:)], A(:), [], @mean);
```